# TFVC replicate into local git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfvc

I am actually facing a small issue at work. We are using TFVC with a Dev and Prod branches.
We only commit changes to the Dev branch once the new feature is finished and fully tested (there's not possibility to have a separate branch per feature, nor to migrate this project to Git).

I need to be able to compare the work i did today with the one from yesterday. There's the shelveset option (via the compare shelveset plugin, but it doesn't work quite well with VS2015).

So the other option I can see is to copy the files flagged as "modifed by" from my workspace into another local git repo, so i can do a daily commit for example.

Any other ideas?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a small script that:

1. copies the modified files since xx date from my local TFS repo to a local git repo.
2. Use [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) to commit the changes
3. Use [GitK](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) to review the history

Answer (score 1):

> Any other ideas?

Use https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

Once the repository cloned with something like (it's better to choose a changeset common between `Dev` and `Prod`branches):

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md#clone-from-a-specific-changeset

you just have to do a pull every times:

```
git tfs pull --rebase
```

Then you could compare your commits.

Comment: This won't work in my case because I want to have a local history, which is not necessarily pushed to tfs.

Comment: @Mo7 And? that's perfectly possible. Their is something that you didn't understand and I still think it's a lot easier than your solution... But whatever, if you are pleased with your solution that's the only important thing!

Comment: let say i start from changeset 1, both my local tfs and git repositories are pulling from it. Then later on i do some changes into my local tfs repo, with no commit, no shelving. Will it  possible to get the changes from my local tfs repo into the local git repo using git-tfs? In my understanding, "git tfs pull --rebase" will pull from the tfs server and not from my local tfs repo. Did I miss something?